# SOLVED: Rails 6, Webpacker, Bootstrap 5, Coffee on Heroku is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, coffeescript, cloudflare, turbolinks

Problem with coffee script on heroku.

At local machine (Ubuntu Linux) all working perfectly, but after deploying changes to Heroku, coffee script stop working, and I can't understand why.

Tried to "reconfigure" webpacker:
And tried to:
`rails assets:clobber`, `bin/webpack --verbose --profile`, `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

- no luck.

Tried to precompile locally: `rake assets:precompile` and then push changes to Heroku: `git push heroku master`

- no luck.

Tried to precompile remotely on Heroku: `heroku run rake assets:clean assets:precompile`

- no luck.

And there is no any errors about coffee in logs via `heroku logs --tail`...

- nothing.

When I insert: `alert('Some test');` into my `app/javascript/packs/application.js` it's worked.

P.S. Rails 6 with Webpacker is some kind of quest... I spend a lot of time to understand and trying to enable usual things which earlier worked fine out from the box in Rails 4 or 5... But now it's seems ok.

UPD1:
I inserted `alert 'test coffee 1'` into first string of my `init_coffee.coffee` and it's worked now, but if I insert some alert after '$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->' then nothing happens.

```
alert 'test coffee 1' # worked
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  alert 'test coffee 2' # not worked
```

UPD2: The coffeescript is not a problem, problem with turbolinks init and any scripts inside that...

Here is my `config/webpacker.yml`
http://pastie.org/p/1RqDZ4haTA4yl6k7EV6b4j

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .coffee
    - .coffee.erb
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

#
check_yarn_integrity: true

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: true

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

And here is my `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "stylesheets/application.sass"
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
  })

  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
      animation: false
    })
  })
})
```

And here is `config/webpack/environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const customConfig = require('./custom')

// coffee
const coffee = require('./loaders/coffee')
environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)

// jquery
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

// init
environment.config.merge(customConfig)
module.exports = environment
```

Here is part of `config/environments/production.rb`

```
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

Comment: Please, specify your local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when I understand that Coffee Script is not a problem and Turbolinks not working properly, I found the solution here: [turbolinks:load event works on local machine not on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164315/turbolinksload-event-works-on-local-machine-not-on-heroku)

The problem was in the Rocket Loader from Cloudflare, I disable it and all working now perfectly.

[image: How to disable Rocket Loader on Cloudflare]